# How to throw if element not found in android

Tags: java, android

It's throwing [UiObjectNotFoundException](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiObjectNotFoundException.html).

```
public UiElement elementBy(UiSelector selector) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        return new UiElement(selector);
}
```

Comment: is this Java? seems like it's iOS code style.

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji nope it's not iOS but Android. check [UiObjectNotFoundException](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiObjectNotFoundException.html)

Comment: @user3334957 include more details like possible code, issue logs, etc. to support your question otherwise it may get closed with the "low quality" reason.

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji it is java->android....

Comment: @PareshMayani the thing is i want to throw when UiElement is not found...right now in this code it will simply return the UiElement if found...but when it is not found i want to throw...so how to do it?

Comment: @PareshMayani i added that throws UiObjectNotFoundException....even if it is not there...it doesnt give any error

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some check whether `UIElement` could be found or not...

To throw exceptions in Java you need the `throw` keyword. For example:

```
if(elementNotFound) {
    throw new UiObjectNotFoundException("UI element not found");
}
```

The `throws` keyword in your method declaration, defines that the method *might* throw the specified exception. It does not throw the actual exceptions.

Read the [Java exceptions lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more details on (throwing) Java exceptions.

Note that it might be possible that `UiElement` does the throwing for you (when it cannot find the corresponding `UiElement` for your `selector`. In this case you do not need to throw the exception again, just keep the `throws` part of your method declaraion. You need to read the documentation of the `UiElement` class to be sure whether this is the case or not.

Comment: what will be for the above scenario?

Comment: Depends on whether the constructor of `UiElement` throws the exception. If not, you need to manually check whether an element is/could be found and if not throw the exception yourself (as shown my the example code).

Comment: yes...i have to throw it manually...so how to check whether the element is found or not?

Comment: public UiElement elementBy(UiSelector selector) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        //return new UiElement(selector);
        if(new UiElement(selector) != null) {
            return new UiElement(selector);
        }
        else {
            throw new UiObjectNotFoundException("UI element not found");
        }
    }

Comment: `new UiElement()` is **never** `null` so that check does not work. The required check depends on the class methods of `UiElement`, in order for you to obtain this information.